# In git, how do I undo all changes and move a branch without deleting it?

Tags: git

I don't have permissions to delete a branch. My situation is most easily described with an illustration. Say the master trunk commits are called, M1, M2, ... and the branch commits are called B1, B2 and so on

```
M1 - M2 - M3 - M4 - M5
      \
       B1 - B2
```

I need to undo commits B1 and B2, and then actually have the branch (with new commits) coming off of M4, so something like this:

```
M1 - M2 - M3 - M4 - M5
                \
                 Bnew1 - Bnew2
```

Again, I can't actually *delete* the branch, and it needs to keep the same name. I don't really care about whether I trash the history of branch 'B'. Also, assume everything has already been pushed. How do I do this?

Comment: You're leaving out some relevant information. Why can't you delete the branch? Do you mean you can't delete it locally, or you can delete the remote version?

Comment: Remote... everything has been pushed and needs to end up pushed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can checkout branch B and do a git rebase.

`git checkout B`

`git rebase M4`

Where M4 is the SHA of the commit M4.

That should move your branch to a new base.
Although if branch B has been pushed, and you still do a rebase, be prepared for some work if you are only contributor or some curses if you are a team worker.

Comment: Thanks, this was a good answer, but I modified the question to add that 'everything has already been pushed'

Comment: After the rebase is done, you can force push the branch to the remote using `git push <remote> -f`. That will overwrite the remote branch, unless the remote has force pushing disabled with the `deny.nonFastForward` configuration.

Comment: Thanks @Cupcake. This is what I meant by being cursed by teammates. If you push changed history, everyone has to pull it and set it up. It's an inconvenience at the best.